# Google Subtokens for Android App

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, auth-token

I am developing an Android app that asks for permission to view my Google profile and email. I allow the app permission to view it, but the "Authorized Apps and Sites" section of my Google account page doesn't list my app. Is there any way to make my app show up so that users can revoke access if they wanted to. It is mostly for testing, so I can force it to ask me for permission over and over but...

It seems like it should be possible, seeing that the iOS version of my app does it, and some other Android apps do it. I just can't find any documentation on how to make my app show up with what information it uses.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, though the capability hasn't fully launched yet.  It will be available in Google Play Services, documented here:

https://developers.google.com/android/google-play-services/

Specifically, you'll need to use `GoogleAuthUtil.getToken()`:

[https://developers.google.com/android/google-play-services/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil#getToken(android.content.Context, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)](https://developers.google.com/android/google-play-services/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil#getToken%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

It's pretty simple.  Small amount of information about it in a Google I/O presentation I gave this year:
http://oauth2-preso.appspot.com/#51.  Video is also available on the [I/O site](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/gooio2012/604/).  The [Building Android Applications that use Web APIs](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/gooio2012/121/) session may have deeper info.

Comment: Hi Ryan, I'm using GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(). The user is asked to authorize the app the first time (UserRecoverableNotifiedException), but I cannot figure out how to deauthorize the app after. Can you please explain this?

Comment: Hey @Ryan Boyd, this used to work for me, but only a few days ago it stopped working and now it throws this error com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: Unknown. Any idea why? Is there something wrong with my scopes? https://gist.github.com/lawloretienne/7351151